# Sending back img with text

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am writing simple blog app. So this is what looks like my schema for post:

```
const postSchema = new Schema({
    img: String,
    title: String,
    content: String,
    date: String
  });
```

I am uploading img file into /uploads folder and saving the path to this img as a string for each post.

I am wondering how can I send this to the client side. For now, I am sending the post as JSON. No problem with **text(title, content, and date)** to display but the image is a little bit a headache.

How to do this in a proper way?

I will be using React+Redux for the client side of this blog.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the fs module to access the filesystem;

```
 fs = require('fs');
```

And in the callback for receiving GET request:

```
 var img = fs.readFileSync('./pathToImage');
 res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/gif' });
 res.end(img, 'binary');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `react` and `redux` on the client-side, you probably want to just translate the *server-side* path into a *client-side* path. As an example, if your server is serving files from: `/path/to/server/public` and you are uploading to `/path/to/server/public/uploads`, you probably want to just send the URL as `/uploads`.

On the *client-side*, you can then simply display your URL using the relative path, like:

```
import { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class Post extends Component {
  ...
  render() {
    <div className="post">
      /* Any other rendering you want to do here */
      <img src={this.props.img} />
    </div>
  }
}
export default connect(
  /* Assuming your Redux store has the post stored as `post` */
  state => state.post,
)(Post)
```